# Recorded voice to caller in iphone

Tags: android, iphone

I have an voice record in my iPhone if suppose I call to friends number as soon as he take the call he should be able to listen voice I already recorded. Is it possible in iphone and android?

Answer (score 4):

Answer is **`NO`**

This is not possible as far as `iPhone` is concerned. We loose control over our application when any call comes or go and control is over to Calling application.

Answer (score 2):

Being an Java ME, Android Developer I have no idea about the iPhone, but i guess you got the iPhone answer from Jennis's answer.

Coming to the Android, let me give you guide you some points,

Yes, you can achieve this requirement in Android Technology. You need to user [Telephony Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) API. There is a state called `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` this will help you to achieve your goal.